# How can I see aggregated sales per account according to it's parent account?

Tags: hierarchy

Our accounts are structured into hierarchies, each can have it's own opptys.

I need a report that aggregates the sales/opptys to the parent (even for a multi-tiered tree - more than 2 levels)

How can I do it?

for simplicity - I need closed won only.

Answer (score 1):

For viewing only, you could create a Visualforce page. I've not included any code here because it'd be relatively involved.

If you want it to be reportable, you can create some rollup triggers to keep the data in sync. Here's a rough version I whipped up:

### Account Custom Fields

```
    Rollup Child Amount, Number (16, 2)
    Closed Won Amount, Number (16, 2)
```

### Opportunity Trigger

```
trigger RollupOpportunityToAccount on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    set<id> accountids = new set<id>();
    opportunity[] records = new opportunity[0];
    if(Trigger.new != null) {
        records.addAll(Trigger.new);
    }
    if(Trigger.old != null) {
        records.addAll(Trigger.old);
    }
    for(Opportunity record: records) {
        accountids.add(record.accountid);
    }
    accountids.remove(null);
    Account[] accounts = new Account[0];
    for(Id accountId: accountids) {
        accounts.add(new Account(Id=accountId));
    }
    update accounts;
}
```

### Account Trigger

```
trigger SumAndRollupAccountToParent on account (before update, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore) {
        for(AggregateResult sum:[SELECT   ParentId ParentId, SUM(Rollup_Child_Amount__c) Amount1, 
                                          SUM(Closed_Won_Amount__c) Amount2
                                 FROM     Account
                                 WHERE    ParentId IN :Trigger.new
                                 GROUP BY ParentId]) {
            Trigger.newMap.get((Id)sum.get('ParentId')).Rollup_Child_Amount__c = 
                (Decimal)sum.get('Amount1')+(Decimal)sum.get('Amount2');
        }
        for(AggregateResult sum:[SELECT   AccountId AccountId, SUM(Amount) Amount 
                                 FROM     Opportunity 
                                 WHERE    IsWon = TRUE AND 
                                          AccountId IN :Trigger.new 
                                 GROUP BY AccountId]) {
            Trigger.newMap.get((Id)sum.get('AccountId')).Closed_Won_Amount__c =
                 (Decimal)sum.get('Amount');
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        Set<Id> parentids = new Set<Id>();
        Account[] records = new Account[0];
        if(trigger.new != null) {
            records.addAll(Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.old != null) {
            records.addAll(Trigger.old);
        }
        for(Account record: records) {
            parentids.add(record.parentid);
        }
        parentids.remove(null);
        Account[] parents = new Account[0];
        for(Id parentId: parentids) {
            parents.add(new Account(Id=parentId));
        }
        update parents;
    }
}
```

After this, all that's left is to run a data load against all opportunities, and everything should roll up automatically.

Comment: n.b. for others reading this for the first time (like me) this very helpful answer will be lifetime-to-date amounts, not, say, current year or last year's values

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom report type on Opportunities or Accounts with Opportunities.
2. On that report type use "add fields via lookup" and add Parent -> Parent -> Parent... Account Name as many times as you can. You should be able to add it up to 5 times (which is equivalent of us being able to use the "dot" to traverse relationships up to 5 times in SOQL)
3. Create a report based on this report type with multiple filter criteria joined with `OR`:

   - Parent Name equals Acme
   - (OR) Parent : Parent equals Acme
   - (OR) Parent : Parent : Parent equals Acme
   - ...
4. Use the "standard" URL hacking tricks to pass the `pv0`, `pv1` etc at runtime
5. (If you have multiple accounts with same name then maybe the Id field would be better)

This should work nicely to be run for one particular Account (add a link to it to custom links section?).

It wouldn't  be as nice if you want to see all Opportunities rolled up. The reports can't end up having more rows that there really are Opps so you'd need to decide at which summary level you'd want to see it (by Grandparents? By Parents?) so the grandparent can "steal" the rows from parents if that's how you wish to see it grouped

Although if you already have the fields added to the report type you could add them to report columns too and summarize by them. Summary report would be bit hard to read though, such stuff looks cleaner in table report. Experiment with matrix format too - rows would be "grandparent & parents", cols - maybe Stage (could be something dummy just to have the field to put in the column grouping)?

---

There's an alternative trick to achieve similar result - make a formula field on Account, call it "ultimate parent" or something, value similar to

```
BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
    BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.Name,
        BLANKVALUE(Parent.Name,
            Name
        )
    )
)
```

(just don't blame me if reports filtered by this take time to load)